# Getting an empty list for pdf2image (convert_from_bytes)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, poppler, pdf2image

I am trying to convert PDF to images using `convert_from_bytes` function from `pdf2image` package.

I have an application on 2 servers, on one server it is able to make the conversion properly, but on the other one it is giving me an empty list `[]`.

I have `Poppler` in place as well. I am using `pdf2image 1.13.1`.

I don't have any issues on server 1 but I am getting an issue on server 2.

As the network is restricted does `pdf2image` need internet access?

[image]

please find the above code

when I print images on Server 1 I get the **[<PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=3807x4944 at 0x2DBF3FD1388>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=3807x4944 at 0x2DBF3FD12C8>]**

but for the same code hosted on the server 2 gives me an empty list

I appreciate your help! Thanks.

Comment: Hello! Please, would you mind providing actual part of your code, so people can help you out?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have updated my question with a screenshot